# Reading a .xlsx and accessing cell values but not by their position

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

this is my first question so sorry in advance if I make some explanation mistakes.

I'm coding in python 2.7.
I wrote a .xlsx (Excel) file (it could have been a .xls, I don't really need the macro + VBA at this point). The Excel file looks like this:

[image: Excel screenshot]

The values are linked with the name of the column and the name of the line. For example, I have a column named "Curve 1" and a line named "Number of extremum". So in that cell I wrote "1" if the curve1 has 1 extremum. 
I want to take this value in order to manipule it in a python script. 
I know I can use *xlrd module* with *open workbook* and put the values of the line 1 ("Number of extremum") in a list and then only take the first one (corresponding to the column "Curve 1" and so to the value "1" I want), but this isn't what I would like to have.

Instead, I would like to access the "1" cell value by only giving to the python script the strings "Curve 1" and "Number of extremum" and python would access to the cell at the meeting of the two and take its value : "1". Is it possible ?

I would like to do this because the Excel file would change in time and cells could be moved. So if I try to access cell value by it's "position number" (like line 1, column 1), I would have a problem if a column or a line is added at this position. I would like not to have to edit again the python script if there's some editing in the xlsx file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is a popular 3rd party library for reading/writing datasets. You can use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for efficient scalar access via row and column labels:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

# extract value
val = df.at['N of extremum', 'Curve 1']
```

Comment: Thank you ! Would that script be different if we had a .xls, .xlsm or a .csv ? Would that script be the same if it was on python 3 ?

Comment: You should look at [Pandas I/O Tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for formats supported natively.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy using Pandas. To obtain the cell you want you can just use `loc` which allows you to specify the row and column just like you want.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df.loc['N of extremum', 'Curve 1']
```